# What would you call a font size between "small" and "regular"

Tags: typography, design-system

I have these tokens in a design system for font sizes:

- tiny
- small
- ???
- regular
- medium
- large
- huge
- mega
- giga

Design needs to add a size between `small` and `regular` and I'm stuck trying to find something that makes sense… Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you instead considered the text in terms of semantics in the UI? Perhaps [h1, h2, h3...p]? That maps to the developers view in terms of implementation ease and understanding.

Comment: Who will be using these sizes?

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to the User Experience StackExchange!

You can use the following terms to denote size between small and regular.

- Compact
- Small-Regular
- Small +

Here is the link to a similar question: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/163605/what-would-you-call-size-that-fits-between-small-and-medium

Comment: Yeah, I saw that link. That's actually where it was suggested to ask in the UX Stack… :) Thanks!

Comment: "Compact" is often used for this purpose in [car sizes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vehicle_size_class), which I think makes it a good choice here.

Answer (score 2):

**In CSS various font size values are :**
medium
xx-small
x-small 
small
large
x-large 
xx-large
smaller
larger

You can probably use x-small and then small and regular

Comment: A reference for the CSS font-size property: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-size

Answer (score 1):

If you’re going with “mega” and “giga”, how about

- nano
- tiny
- small
- regular
- ...

, which would require skewing the scale, though.

There’s also the term [“smedium”](https://www.google.co.uk/amp/s/www.urbandictionary.com/define.php%3Fterm=smedium&amp=true) i’ve been hearing more often lately. I think they use it mainly for clothes, but it might work here too.

Answer (score 0):

Other possibilities are combined words like:

- sub-regular
- regular-reduced
- small-medium

Or a word with a corresponding meaning:

- reduced
- fitted
- low
- modest
- decreased
- scaled

But in any case it could be helpful if you append each fontsize with a small marker, to give a clue about the size, like (+) (++) (+++)